# Dynamic dispatch and inheritance in python

Tags: python, dynamic-dispatch

I'm trying to modify Guido's multimethod (dynamic dispatch code):

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605

to handle inheritance and possibly out of order arguments.

e.g. (inheritance problem)

```
class A(object):
  pass

class B(A):
  pass

@multimethod(A,A)
def foo(arg1,arg2):
  print 'works'


foo(A(),A()) #works

foo(A(),B()) #fails
```

Is there a better way than iteratively checking for the super() of each item until one is found?

e.g. (argument ordering problem)
I was thinking of this from a collision detection standpoint.

e.g.

```
foo(Car(),Truck()) and
foo(Truck(), Car()) and
```

should both trigger

```
foo(Car,Truck) # Note: @multimethod(Truck,Car) will throw an exception if @multimethod(Car,Truck) was registered first?
```

I'm looking specifically for an 'elegant' solution. I know that I could just brute force my way through all the possibilities, but I'm trying to avoid that. I just wanted to get some input/ideas before sitting down and pounding out a solution.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at PEAK-Rules which is another implementation of generic dispatch in python which can handle inheritance. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PEAK-Rules

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the inheritance issue: This can be done with a slight change to MultiMethod. (Iterating through self.typemap and checking with `issubclass`):

```
registry = {}

class MultiMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.typemap = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        types = tuple(arg.__class__ for arg in args) # a generator expression!
        for typemap_types in self.typemap:
            if all(issubclass(arg_type,known_type)
                   for arg_type,known_type in zip(types,typemap_types)):
                function = self.typemap.get(typemap_types)
                return function(*args)
        raise TypeError("no match")
    def register(self, types, function):
        if types in self.typemap:
            raise TypeError("duplicate registration")
        self.typemap[types] = function

def multimethod(*types):
    def register(function):
        name = function.__name__
        mm = registry.get(name)
        if mm is None:
            mm = registry[name] = MultiMethod(name)
        mm.register(types, function)
        return mm
    return register

class A(object):
  pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(object):
    pass

@multimethod(A,A)
def foo(arg1,arg2):
  print 'works'


foo(A(),A()) #works

foo(A(),B()) #works

foo(C(),B()) #raises TypeError
```

Note that `self.typemap` is a dict, and dicts are unordered. So if you use @multimethod to register two functions, one whose types are subclasses of the other, then the behavior of `foo` may be undefined. That is, the result would depend on which `typemap_types` comes up first in the loop `for typemap_types in self.typemap`.

Answer (score 2):

`super()` returns a proxy object, not the parent class (because you can have multiple inheritance), so that wouldn't work. Using `isinstance()` is your best bet, although there's no way to make it as elegant as the dictionary lookups using `type(arg)`.

I don't think allowing alternative argument orderings is a good idea; it's liable to lead to nasty surprises, and making it compatible with inheritance as well would be a significant headache. However, it would be quite simple to make a second decorator for "use this function if all the arguments are of type A", or "use this function if all the arguments are in types {A, B, E}".